# Upgrade of WP7 with Zune on Windows 7N raises error 80072FA

Tags: zune, windows-phone

whenever I try to update my Windows phone 7 on Windows 7N with Zune the error 80072fa8 is raised.

I tried restarting the System Event Notification Service but avail. It doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide more informations like Zune Version and WP7 OS Version. Also your Computer OS Version. Also the phone provider. It sounds like your phone provider had a bad OS update and now you need to send the hardware back or do a hardware reset. But first, let us know some details.